# Android: Can't update TextView text in activity from fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, spotify

I have a fragment, and for communicating with parent activity (see next block of code) I use an interface. I am including a basic example but the issue is that my TextView is not updating on the activity when calling the function updateTextView() from an Spotify OnPlaybackEvent, if I call this same function from the click of a button it works. I have tried with Handlers and runonuithread but nothing seems to work.

This is my fragment:

```
public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment implements SpotifyPlayer.NotificationCallback, ConnectionStateCallback {

    public ImageView playButton;
    public TrackOperations trackOperationsCallback;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.player_fragment, container, false);

        playButton = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.playButton);


        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //THIS WORKS!
                trackOperationsCallback.updateTextView();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaybackEvent(PlayerEvent playerEvent) {
        if(playerEvent.equals(kSpPlaybackNotifyTrackDelivered)){
           //THIS IS PRINTED WHEN A SONG ENDS
           Log.d(spoty.TAG, "Player: Event " + playerEvent);

           //BUT THIS DONT WORK
           trackOperationsCallback.updateTextView();
       }
    }

    public interface TrackOperations {
        public void updateTextView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);

        try {
            trackOperationsCallback = (TrackOperations) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement TrackOperations");
        }
    }

}
```

This is my parent activity:

```
 public class QueueActivity extends Activity implements PlayerFragment.TrackOperations {

     private TextView queueSong;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

         queueSong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.queueSong);
     }

     @Override
     public void updateTextView(){
         //THIS IS PRINTED IN BOTH CASES
         Log.d(spoty.TAG, "Called!");

         //THIS WORKS IF IS CALLED FROM THE BUTTON CLICK OF THE FRAGMENT 
         //BUT DONT WORK WHEN CALLED FROM THE EVENT IN FRAGMENT
         queueSong.setText("ANY RANDOM TEXT");
     }
}
```

I have days struggling with this, so any advice will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In which thread `onPlaybackEvent` gets called?

Comment: What do you actually do in updateCurrentTrack()? The problem might be the code in that method.

Comment: updateCurrentTrack() = updateTextField() = updateTextView()?
You are mistakenly using different method names for the same method right? Or are there more than one method in your interface?

Comment: It seems you were not declared and defined updateTextView().

Comment: Sorry I updated my error naming the function, it must be called updateTextView(). Was an error when trying to simplfying the example in here. Please check again now.

Comment: About the thread, I am not sure, onPlaybackEvent gets called inside the fragment. But I have tried wrapping the setText method in handler or runonuithread without luck. Thanks.

Comment: If I put a log.d inside the updateTextView function, it gets printed in both cases. So, the function is getting called but the textview is not getting updated.

Answer (score 1):

This can not be the best way, but whenever I have trouble with data transfer I solve it by using SharedPreferences, including Fragment to Fragment comunication. This will surely solve your problem

Comment: Thanks Carlos, but this will not solve the issue. The function is getting called and data is being received by this. The only issue is the TextView not updating its value.

Comment: Perhaps the TV is not being instantiated correctly once you call it, try moving the line "         queueSong = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.queueSong);
"
to the updateTextView method

Comment: I'm sorry then  :/